Capturing screenshot in the PowerApps using a single screen with 90+ fields (Form connected to SharePoint)
I have developed a canvas app that includes a form connected to a SharePoint list with 90 columns. On one of the screens, I have added all 90 data cards.
To meet our current requirements, I need to capture a screenshot of this page that includes all the fields, or alternatively, generate a PDF of the screen capturing all the content.
Could you please provide guidance on the best approach to achieve this?

I have tried the PDF functionality, but the problem is it is taking only those fields which are visible on the screen not the entire screen content.
Created power automate flow which will add the details into excel and then share that excel via mail, the problem is user has to wait for the mail and user wants in PDF or image.

Please suggest any alternatives in PowerApps UI. Thanks in advance!
